# Passing network bonding to other port

Tags: routing, network

I currently developing network for office place using mikrotik cloud core router, the outline is 2 ether interface into 1 bonding interface and distributing into 2 ether interface or maybe 1 ether interface.

Here is the Topology : [network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAzY6.png)

ether1 and ether2 is used to connect from ISP and i bonded it for agregation purpose, but i don't understand how to passing bonding interface to ether3 and ether4 to switch ? what configuration should be set for this ? youtube and google are not clear for me.

could anyone give me more detail configuration ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: For a device to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer that. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 2):

> ether1 and ether2 is used to connect from ISP and i bonded it for agregation purpose

That won't work *unless your ISP specifically supports* that kind of bonding/LAG. Simple bonding can't ever work between different ISPs.

If that is not the case you need to use/configure *IP load balancing*. I don't know whether your router can do that or you need additional hardware. IP load balancing can be a delicate subject and you'll have to make up your mind what specifics need to be configured - by source user/IP, destination, protocol, ...

> i don't understand how to passing bonding interface to ether3 and ether4 to switch

You need to configure a LAG trunk on each side, preferably using the LACP protocol (which takes care of potential misconnections).

Note that link aggregation generally uses a *static traffic distribution* - by MAC addresses, IP addresses and/or L4 port numbers, depending on the hardware and its configuration - check the manuals.

That way, any single flow will always use a single physical path and you'll only employ different physical paths with different traffic flows with L4 distribution. Generally, L4 distribution is best.

IP/L3 distribution keeps traffic between any two IP entities always on the same path. It works across routed links but cannot aggregate link bandwidth between any two nodes.

Finally, MAC/L2 distribution holds traffic together between link layer entities - so LAG is basically useless between routed links since they always use the same source/destination MAC address pairs.